# Does a weak learner really have to have error < 1/2 for ANY distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

Everything I've learned about weak learners ( in relation to AdaBoost specifically ) says that they have to have error < 1/2 for ANY distribution of training data.   I think I must be misinterpreting this, so I would appreciate it if someone could point out the flaw in my logic below:

Say a weak learner misclassifies just a single example ( call it x ).  Then, consider the distribution that has a 100% weight on that example x and 0% weight on every other example.  Clearly the weak learner will have an error of 1 for this distribution, which is > 1/2.  By my understanding of the definition, that means it's not really a weak learner.  Thus, if a weak learner misclassifies even a single piece of sample data, then it can't have error < 1/2 for any distribution.  But that means a weak learner has to be perfect, which I know defies the whole point of a boosting ensemble of weak learners and is just crazy talk.

So, I must be misunderstanding what it means for a weak learner to have an error < 1/2 for any distribution.  What does "any" actually mean?

Comment: A weak-learner has only one requirement: it needs to be better than random-guessing (which would mean error==0.5 i suppose). It's hard to work with your example because it's about one 'action' and not about multiple samples. At least to my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

In the 2 classes problem a random learner will error=0.5. In practice this is the worst error, since you can edit each learner that has more than 0.5 error to exactly the opposite - meaning that the opposite learner error will be 1-(the error of the first learner).
Moreover, the measuring of the error on 1 example is very problematic and probably not represent correctly the true error.
So, if the worst error is 0.5 (as we saw we can make any learner to have error less than 0.5), the boosting required a bit more accuracy in each weak learner in order to combine them together and "boost".

Comment: right, a random learner will have error = 0.5.  But a specific learner could have error worse than that, if it's classifying against an adversarial distribution, right?  So is the requirement only that a "weak" learner must have error rate < 0.5 for a uniform distribution?  I must have misunderstood when I hear it had to be for _ANY_ distribution.